# How do mobile HTML5 apps use the OAuth 2 protocol?

Tags: api, mobile, cordova, oauth

I am using PhoneGap to create a mobile app with HTML, CSS, and JS.

I need to implement some sort of authentication to connect to my API - and I am thinking that OAuth 1 or OAuth 2 should do the trick nicely.

However, with OAuth 1, I would need to store the consumer secret in my JS which would expose it to anybody with a brain.

With OAuth 2, I can get around exposing a secret by not using one altogether, and simply providing a redirect URL that was pre-registered with the API provider. This guarantees that the user is only ever sent back to the correct URL (they can't be hijacked).

However, with PhoneGap, I can't really provide a redirect url, because the PhoneGap url would be something like file://www/index.html...

How is it possible to use Oauth 1 or OAuth 2 with a mobile HTML5 app?

Answer (score 4):

Libby has a good tutorial on how to do OAuth 1 with PhoneGap at:

http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt5p1

as for your consumer secret you could store it in the native code then use a Plugin to retrieve it from the native side from JavaScript. There is already one available for iOS called [Keychain](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/Keychain).

Answer (score 1):

For people new to this topic, the Intel Developer Zone also has a [tutorial on using OAuth2 with PhoneGap/Cordova](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/article/oauth2-with-intelxdk-cordova-html5). To avoid the use of the client secret within the application you would use the OAuth2 Implicit Flow. From the link above

> Here are the steps involved in doing a Oauth2 Implicit Grant flow in a
>   Cordova* HTML5 app:
>
> 1. Open Oauth2 authorization page in Cordova InAppBrowser
> 2. Get the access_token from the redirected URL hash fragment using the loadstart event listener